# Remove space between lines in HTML in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, spacing

I'm trying to get rid of the pesky space that exists currently between my lines. I have them separated by different headings for editing reasons (bold, regular, color). How do I remove this space?

See below

```
<h3><span style="font-size: 14px;">XXXXXXXXX</span></h3>
<h4><span style="font-size: 14px;">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<a href="mailto:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">XXXXXXXXXXXXX/a> </span></h4>
```

Comment: Two things. First, your link isn't closed properly. Second, which space are you referring to?

Comment: @j08691 Probably margin and padding.

Comment: @JuanMendes - That's what I'm unclear on. If it's the heading's padding/margin, then it's simple, but why does the OP say "I have them separated by different headings for editing reasons". Unclear to me.

Comment: sorry if I was vague; i'm referring to the spaces existing between h3 and h4 headings….it automatically puts a space between the two headings

Comment: Do you mean the default margin that header elements have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS

```
<h3 style="padding:0; margin:0"><span style="font-size: 14px;">XXXXXXXXX</span></h3>
```

Ideally, you would define the CSS in a separate file

```
h3, h4 {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

For further control you can add class names (so it doesn't apply to all h3s) and chose padding/margin sides

```
<h3 class="news">...</h3>

h3.news {
   padding-bottom: 2px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: this worked thank you. if I want to control the distance between an image and these headings do I use a similar method? this is being used for a BIO page….staff photo and then name, title, contact below

Comment: @user3565453 You can change to amount of padding and margin.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS selector for `h3` and `h4`  tags:

```
h4, h3 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq6aQ/)

Comment: That's a CSS element selector, not a class selector. I think the term you're looking for is CSS ruleset. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax